# Proof involving k-permutations

Tags: combinatorics

For any nonnegative integers k and m satisfying $0 ≤ k ≤ m$, prove that the total number of $k$-permutations of a set of m elements is $\frac{m!}{(m − k)!}$.
I have learned about by proofs by strong and weak induction, and in this case I am thinking of using strong induction, but I have no idea how I would follow through with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably better off simplifying the formula
$$
  \frac{m!}{(m-k)!} = m(m-1)(m-2)\ldots(m-k+1),
$$
and directly prove that a $k$-permutation can be chosen by selecting one element out of $m$, then another out of $m-1$, and so forth until a final element out of $m-k+1$. (There is also a proof using the factorials directly, but it uses group theory.)